# FreeReport: how to format If-Then

Tags: delphi, formatting, fastreport

I use FreeReport (from FastReport) and I need to implement such code:

```
If TOTALPAGES > 1 then Pageheader.visible = false
```

I do not know, where to write this code, I tried to put inside a pascal code, it not works.

And this record do not works also:

```
[IFF([TOTALPAGES] > 1,'PAGEHEADER.VIBLE=0')]
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: with *totalpages* you hit an interesting topic.

Answer (score 2):

The postition to usually place code would be a the `OnBeforePrint` (*) event of then *PageHeader* band, **but** this won't work with `<TotalPages#>`

```
procedure PageHeader1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin     
    TfrxPageHeader(Sender).visible :=  (<TotalPages#> = 1);                                                                                                        
end;
```

The problem with this approach is `<TotalPages#>` won't be evaluated at this time.
A second problem here is the showing or hiding the PageHeader might affect the count of the pages. To achieve the desired result you will have to render the report by `frxreport1.PrepareReport(true);`. You might do this twice, with visible PageHeader and unvisble PageHeader. Every part of a report can be accesses by `frxReport1.FindObject`. Make sure this is assigned before using it.
As a sidenote, another place to effect the objects on printing/preview is the `OnPrint` event of the frxReport component, which will be called for every object before it's rendered.

```
begin
  frxReport1.FindObject('PageHeader1').Visible := true;
  frxReport1.PrepareReport(true);

  // in my test case 2 Pages
  Showmessage(IntToStr(frxReport1.PreviewPages.Count));

  frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;

  frxReport1.FindObject('PageHeader1').Visible := false;
  frxReport1.PrepareReport(true);

  // in my test case 1 Page
  Showmessage(IntToStr(frxReport1.PreviewPages.Count));

  frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;
end;
```

The usual place implement report code:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try similar code inside report:
[if([PAGE#] < [TOTALPAGES], 'Ok', 'Not Ok')]